# Is it possible to get `ps` to render thread names in wide mode?

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I am using the following version of PS inside a container:

```
bash-4.2$ ps --version
ps from procps-ng 3.3.15
```

The command `ps -eL` shows the thread names, but they are truncated:

```
 3972 12684 ?        00:00:00 OkHttp TaskRunn
 3972 21419 ?        00:00:00 OkHttp TaskRunn
```

I tried passing `w` with `ps -eLw` but it's ignored without error.
I tried `ps -eL -F`, but it renders process names and not thread names.

**Is it possible to get this version of `ps` to render thread names in wide mode?**

Comment: @GillesQuénot  I have tested your answer, but it does not address the question. 
I want *thread names* and your answer only offers process names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Thread names are limited to 16 bytes in Linux kernel. Which is 15 characters and the C-string `\0` (`null`) terminating char. Which can also be seen in your example of `OkHttp TaskRunn` consisting of 14 letters and a space.

Check these for more info:

- [pthread_getname_np docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getname_np.3.html)

> The thread name is a meaningful C language string, whose length is restricted to 16 characters, including the terminating null byte ('\0')

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534499/7264739)